# Squid3 и IP amazon aws за Nat

Tags: proxy, amazon, squid

Здравствуйте, хочу настроить squid3 для ipv6 прокси как на привычных хостингах (настраивал на arubacloud, vpsville, cloudbox), чтобы можно было работать напрямую со статичным айпи, но судя по ссылке https://serverfault.com/questions/765663/static-public-ip-address-on-amazon-ec2 - All EC2 instances sit behind Amazon's NAT infrastructure. It is not possible to directly assign an EIP or other public IP directly to an EC2 instance работать напрямую не получится.

Соответственно в /etc/network/interfaces нет возможности заменить предустановленную строку

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

на

```
iface eth0 inet static
```

И соответственно cache.log или лог-файл сквида выдает вот такое:

```
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 18 to 35.161.222.146:30007: (99) Cannot assign requested address
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 19 to 35.161.222.146:30008: (99) Cannot assign requested address
2017/01/03 09:30:09 kid1| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 20 to 35.161.222.146:30009: (99)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в таком случае быть на амазоне? Буду много благодарен